# What is the name of this low-growing plant with pink flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers, perennials

[image]

The plant is small, just about 4 inches tall, growing in my front yard, in Sydney, Australia. The leaves are grass like and the little flower is quite fragrant. I just can't recall the name, can someone identify it please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a [freesia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freesia), a group of iris-relatives.

Due to their interesting flower shape, strong scent and comparatively low "fussyness" they have been cultivated and hybridized a lot over time. They come in a wide range of colours and sizes.

Many of us will know them as cut flower where they contribute scent and visual interest to bouquets; because the individual flowers per stalk tend to open over time, it makes them quite long-lasting, provided spent flowers are removed.

Comment: Ah, freesia. Thank you so much Stephie. I can sleep tonight.